# How do I access ViewBag from JS

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, viewbag

My attempted methods.

Looking at the JS via browser, the `@ViewBag.CC` is just blank... (missing)

```
        var c = "#" + "@ViewBag.CC";
        var d = $("#" + "@ViewBag.CC").value;
        var e = $("#" + "@ViewBag.CC").val();

        var c = "@ViewBag.CC";
        var d = $("@ViewBag.CC").value;
        var e = $("@ViewBag.CC").val();
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

if you are using razor engine template then do the following

in your view write :

```
<script> var myJsVariable = '@ViewBag.MyVariable' </script>
```

**UPDATE:**
A more appropriate approach is to define a set of configuration on the master layout for example, base url, facebook API Key, Amazon S3 base URL, etc ...```

```
<head>
 <script>
   var AppConfig = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(new {
    baseUrl: Url.Content("~"),
    fbApi: "get it from db",
    awsUrl: "get it from db"
   }));
 </script>
</head>
```

And you can use it in your JavaScript code as follow:

```
<script>
  myProduct.fullUrl = AppConfig.awsUrl + myProduct.path;
  alert(myProduct.fullUrl);
</script>
```

Comment: Why the `@` before the `<script>` ?

Comment: Minus the @ symbol before Script, and this is the correct answer. Thanks

Comment: you need the @ sign when using traditional <script> tags, just tested

Comment: @amd this is very helpful. +1

Answer (score 15):

try:  `var cc = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.CC)`

Comment: @Doomsknight. And I hope you won't use it.

Comment: Well in that case, check the value of ViewBag.CC server side, you might not be setting it in some case.

Answer (score 9):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
                showWarning('@ViewBag.Message');
      });

</script>
```

You can use ViewBag.PropertyName in javascript like this.

Comment: Im not sure wht showWarning does. (didnt do anything for me) but the rest did contain the correct value. So I saw `showWarning('2');` in my code.

Comment: I was using this code, it calls just alert and it works fine. you can change alert('@ViewBag.Message'); it will work.

Answer (score 4):

`ViewBag` is **server side** code.
`Javascript` is **client  side** code.

You can't **really** connect them.

You can do something like this:

```
var x = $('#' + '@(ViewBag.CC)').val();
```

But it will get parsed on the server, so you didn't really connect them.

Comment: I think you have an additional bracket? Ive tried similar to this but with `"`.

Comment: @Doomsknight. `'` or `"` is the same thing. Well Did it work?

Comment: On run time i see `var c = $('#' + '2').val();`

Comment: @Doomsknight. O.k. **So it's working...** :) You have `2` in the `ViewBag.CC`

Comment: Seeing the 2 now, Ive gone back to `var c = '@ViewBag.CC';` seems to be working now :/ Maybe running a few methods together were breaking it all. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve the solution, by doing this:

**JavaScript:**

```
var myValue = document.getElementById("@(ViewBag.CC)").value;
```

or if you want to use `jQuery`, then:

**jQuery**

```
var myValue = $('#' + '@(ViewBag.CC)').val();
```

Comment: I guess the javascript alternative might help others +1. Also i think you can just write `'#@(ViewBag.CC)'`

Comment: Yeah, you can be right @Doomsknight, because world consisting multiple solutions :-)

Comment: yes @Doomsknight, You're right. I was just try to elaborate is an easy way. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

None of the existing solutions worked for me. Here's another solution I found that did work:

Controller:

```
TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "your message here";
```

View:

```
let msg = '@TempData["SuccessMessage"]';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Anywhere in HTML: `<input hidden value=@ViewBag.CC id="CC_id" />`

In JS: `var CC= document.getElementById("CC_id").value.toString();`