# How to pass a Viewbag in ng-click

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

```html
<th><a href="javascript:;" ng-click="order(@ViewBag.desc)">Name</a></th>
```

This is the code i am using and want to use view bag data in angular Controller 
Ia am stuck here

Comment: What do you want to achieve by that? Maybe this link http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to pass ViewBag data to js file, because all Razor tags are handled by Razor engine and it works only inside Razor templates. However, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10008084/5501613), you could assign your ViewBag.desc to a js variable and use this variable inside your Angular controller

```
<script>
   var desc = @ViewBag.desc;
</script>
```

and in your controller

```
$scope.desc = desc;
```