# How To Use ViewBag Data In jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

Here I have ViewBag in a controller which contains text i.e `ViewBag.Msg = "No Sprint"`.
And I am trying to use ViewBag.Msg in Jquery to display modal.
Now, the problem is that the script is script never gets executed.
Below is my jQuery.

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        if (@ViewBag.Msg != null)
        {
            $("#myModal").modal();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: What is the resulting client-side code?  Did you just forget to enclose a string in quotes?  Check your browser console for errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access ViewBag from JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008023/how-do-i-access-viewbag-from-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the below code.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        var msg='@ViewBag.Msg';
        if (msg !== '')
        {
            $("#myModal").modal();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use quotation marks for the view bag, as it will appear as a literal string.

If your debugger is not hitting at all, then you have another issue, post your full code. (your .cshtml file and layout)

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        if ('@ViewBag.Msg' != null)
        {
            $("#myModal").modal();
        }
    });
 </script>
```